# How can i share cusome title and description in google plus like facebook?

Tags: php, performance, google-plus

I have a  lot of products and want to share each one with different title and description in Google plus instead of page meta tags. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4):

### Google+

Will recognize:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="The page Title for sharing">
<meta itemprop="description" content="The description less than 200 characters">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/image-200x200.jpg">
```

### Facebook

Open Graph Tags (Other Social networks read it too):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/the-page-thumb-200x200.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="The page Title for sharing" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" /> (or "article")
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yoursite.com/the-url-for-sharing" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The Description less than 200 characters" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site name" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your-facebook-app-id" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="your-facebook-user-id" />
```

### Get app-id

@ https://developers.facebook.com/

Login with your FB credentials and then setup a facebook app.

### Use the Debug tool

@ https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

to see how your Data is seen.

### Twitter Tags

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@publisher_handle">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="The page Title for sharing">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="The description less than 200 characters">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@author_handle">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/image-200x200.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

> instead of page meta tags

You cannot. Google+ will *only* fetch data about the page from the page. You cannot override it with URI parameters or though any JS API.